# Receive an SMS android application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am having problems setting up an app which would receive SMS messages. The thing is when i test the app with android emulator message is being shown, but on physical device that is not the case. And message is being displayed and log message is shown only if app is in ReceivedFragment. Otherwise there is no trail of any message.

I tried to set it up as described on this link: https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-phone-sms-course/Lesson%202/2_p_2_sending_sms_messages.html

I am not getting any positive results and i can say that i am stuck... I have no idea what could be wrong and what produces these kind of app behavior. If anyone can help i would be extremely grateful.

Here are classes which are responsible for handling my messages

SMSReceiver class

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_TEXT = "SMS_TEXT";
    public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
            Bundle pdusBundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pdusBundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

            Intent broadcastSMS = new Intent();
            broadcastSMS.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastSMS.putExtra(SMS_TEXT, message.getMessageBody());
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastSMS);
        }
    }
}
```

Received Fragment

```
public class ReceivedFragment extends Fragment {


    public static ReceivedFragment newInstance() {
        return new ReceivedFragment();
    }

    private SMSReceiver broadcastIntent = new SMSReceiver();
    private SMSReceiver messageIntent;
    private TextView tvReceived;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View receivedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received, container, false);
        tvReceived = receivedView.findViewById(R.id.tv_received);

        messageIntent = new SMSReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                tvReceived.setText(intent.getStringExtra(SMSReceiver.SMS_TEXT));
            }
        };
        return receivedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        IntentFilter telephonyIF = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        IntentFilter actionIF = new IntentFilter("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastIntent, telephonyIF);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(messageIntent, actionIF);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastIntent);
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(messageIntent);
    }
}
```

And Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="mypackage.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".AppService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.SMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I would appreciate if someone would point out what am i doing wrong with this app. Thank you in advance

Comment: All SMS permissions are dangerous, and must be requested at runtime, too, on Marshmallow and above, if targeting 23+. Which versions are you running on?